# Maven GWT 2.0 and Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, gwt

Does anyone know of a good guide for creating a project with the new 2.0 release of GWT using maven and eclipse? I am running into a lot of problems getting them to play nicely together.

For what it's worth, I can create a gwt project using the maven eclipse plugin which works fine, but porting it to maven doesn't work (so a guide for this would be great).

Likewise, I can use the maven plugin (gwt-maven-plugin), but when I import it to eclipse (import -> materialize maven projects), it does not get recognised as a GWT project...

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**EDIT:** I've updated my answer with additional steps provided by the OP. Credits to the OP for the details.

I just broke my Eclipse setup trying to install the latest version of the Google Plugin for Eclipse (for GWT 2.0) so I can't confirm everything but, let's assume the following prerequisites are fulfilled:

- Eclipse 3.5
- Google Plugin for Eclipse (installed from http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.5, see [instructions](http://code.google.com/intl/en/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html))
- m2eclipse Plugin for Eclipse (installed from http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update)

Did you try to:

1. Create a new project from Eclipse (*New > Other...* then select *Maven Project* and choose the *gwt-maven-plugin* archetype).
2. Edit the generated `pom.xml`, update the `gwt.version` property to `2.0.0` (which has been released in the central repo), <strike>add the [Codehaus Snapshot](http://mojo.codehaus.org/using-sandbox-plugins.html) repository</strike> and set the `gwt-maven-plugin` version to <strike>`1.2-SNAPSHOT` (the version 1.2 isn't released in central, this should happen soon)</strike> `1.2` (which has been released in central too).
3. Add a `<runTarget>` to the gwt-maven-plugin configuration as documented in [Using the Google Eclipse Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.1/eclipse/google_plugin.html).
4. Configure the maven-war-plugin as documented in the page mentioned in the previous step.
5. <strike>Manually enable GWT on the project from project preference by setting the *Use Google Web Toolkit* checkbox</strike> This step is unnecessary since you'll be building/running with a Maven run configuration, not the GWT Plugin for Eclipse.

This is how my `pom.xml` actually looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!--
    GWT-Maven archetype generated POM
  -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.demo</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-gwtapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>gwt-maven-archetype-project</name>

  <properties>

      <!-- convenience to define GWT version in one place -->
      <gwt.version>2.0.0</gwt.version>

      <!--  tell the compiler we can use 1.5 -->
      <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>

  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!--  GWT dependencies (from central repo) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>com.mycompany.demo.gwt.Application/Application.html</runTarget>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!--
          If you want to use the target/web.xml file mergewebxml produces,
          tell the war plugin to use it.
          Also, exclude what you want from the final artifact here.
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
          <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>    
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Run the `gwt:eclipse` goal (using m2eclipse Maven2 > build...) to setup your environment and create the launch configuration for your GWT modules.

Run `gwt:compile gwt:run` to compile and run a GWT module in the GWT Hosted mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did as in your post, but also did the additional steps of specifying the GWT SDK (rightclick on project->google-> Web Toolkit settings). It does seem to compile, but when running the project (in eclipse), I don't get any links in the Development Mode tab to open up the app... Any ideas why this is the case?

Comment: Ok, so I (finally) got it to work. Although there still seems to be a problem with eclipse development mode displaying a link to the application. Essentially follow Pascal's answer, but then follow the instructions on http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.1/eclipse/google_plugin.html. Then use "mvn gwt:compile gwt:run" to view the pages.
@Pascal - If you want to append your answer to reflect that  you have to (1) specify in eclipse that the project is a gwt one, (2) change the pom as indicated in the page above, and (3) run 'mvn gwt:eclipse' before compiling I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated my answer accordingly (I've tested this, everything works fine). Thanks again!

Comment: I'm using gwt-maven-plugin without Google Eclipse Plugin.
Project is created with gwt-maven-plugin archetype.
Everything works fine except gwt:debug.
GWT development mode window does not open.
I can't access page with gwt module.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found a solution on:
http://claudiushauptmann.com/tutorial-gwt-maven-and-eclipse-with-m2eclipse.html

Comment: Informative post. Though, Step 5 is unnecessary since you'll be building/running with a Maven run configuration, not the GWT Plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: @rpr: You're right, will update that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @PascalThivent Do you run application only with maven in this case - gwt:run or gwt:debug?
I mean can't you just run it by "Run As-> Web Application (Google)" as it's by default after you create New Web App from Google menu w/o maven integration.
?

Comment: At step one, gwt-maven-plugin is not one of the available archetypes. Do you have any suggestions please?

Answer (score 3):

You can run the following command to generate a Maven GWT project:

webAppCreator -maven -noant -out

For more information:

[GWT webappcreator creating a Maven project: the source attachment does not contain the source for the file URLClassPath.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4314870/gwt-webappcreator-creating-a-maven-project-the-source-attachment-does-not-contai)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case. If you use Google GIN in your project you should add **compile** goal before **gwt:compile**. So the whole sequence would be:

```
compile gwt:compile gwt:run
```

You can read explanation here: 
http://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial#Compilation

Answer (score 1):

An annoying problem with GWT and m2eclipse:

> GWT Development Mode requires all JARs
>   to be placed in WEB-INF/lib. It's
>   especially painful when programmers
>   use m2eclipse, which provides its own
>   Eclipse classpath container.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5693

good news, the workaround is working for me

Answer (score 0):

very useful thread

@Pascal: thank you (I donot have enough reputations to comment on others posts; so here I am posting on what is working for me).

I needed 2.5.1 GWT (not 2.6, the latest) working with maven and eclipse (because sencha GXT is not supported for 2.6 yet). Tried following without luck

1)tried few  archetypes with in eclipse to generate the project

2)modify pom file (based on above discussion) to change versions to 2.5.1

Following worked for me http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/archetype.html

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -DarchetypeArtifactId=gwt-maven-plugin -DarchetypeVersion=2.5.1
 mvn gwt:eclipse
 mvn gwt:run
```