# converting GWT1.7 application to GWT2.0

Tags: maven-2, gwt, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

I am developing a web application in GWT 1.7.Now I am planning to move to GWT 2.0. I am using maven build tool and intellij idea IDE.Can any one tell me the maven plugin for GWT2.0 and how  to run/debug using intellij idea IDE?RIght now I am using GWT Mojo plugin http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've provided detailed steps and a `pom.xml` to use Maven, GWT 2.0 and the [Maven GWT Plugin 1.2](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin-1.2/) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894003/maven-gwt-2-0-and-eclipse/1894270#1894270). All the non Eclipse specific steps (i.e. the Maven part) should apply and help you to update from GWT 1.7 to 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

[gwt-maven-plugin 1.2 has been released](http://groups.google.com/group/codehaus-mojo-gwt-maven-plugin-users/browse_thread/thread/94e32ba985c4b9ea) and now full supports GWT 2.0.

I'm not familiar with IntelliJ IDEA. But, they do [support maven integration](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/ant_maven.html) like any other IDE. You can integrate your maven-gwt project like any other one into IntelliJ.