# How to get GWT 2.0 and Restlet 2.0 to play nice

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, gwt, restlet

I am having trouble getting Restlet to play nice with GWT in the same project. I have been trying the examples from Restlets [website](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/144-restlet.html) to no avail

I am using Eclipse, Maven2 plugin, GWT, and Restlet GWT. I have never used server side code in this GWT project before and I know there is some custom setup involved. I am deploying locally for the time being using the built in Jetty in GWT Hosted Mode. I can get my front end to display but my back end is not executing.

I did add this to my web.xml file which is from the example (for the time being I am trying to drop the example into my project).

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>adapter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.restlet.ext.gwt.GwtShellServletWrapper</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
        <param-value>org.restlet.example.gwt.server.TestServerApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>adapter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I did notice that my web.xml file is located separately from my war deployment directory. My project dir structure is setup as follows.

```
Project Root
   src/main/java
   src/main/resources
   src/main/test
   JRE
   Maven Dependecies
   GWT SDK
   src
      main
          webapp
              WEB-INF
                 web.xml
   target
   war
      <my project dir>
      WEB-INF
         lib
   pom.xml
```

So there is no web.xml under my war files WEB-INF directory. I am new to this type of application so it is most likely a matter of me not understanding the directory structure and how my GWT project is compiling into these dirs.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <!--
    POM generated by gwt-maven-plugin archetype
  -->
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.tdc</groupId>
  <artifactId>Propspace</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>

      <!-- convenience to define GWT version in one place -->
      <gwt.version>2.0.0</gwt.version>

      <!--  tell the compiler we can use 1.5 -->
      <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
      <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>

  </properties>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
        </snapshots>
        <id>com.smartgwt</id>
        <name>smartgwt</name>
        <url>http://www.smartclient.com/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>

      <!--  GWT dependencies (from central repo) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
      <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
      <version>${gwt.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.7</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.json</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.xml</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.gwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <outputDirectory>war/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>generateAsync</goal>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <runTarget>com.tdc.Propspace.Application/Application.html</runTarget>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!--
          If you want to use the target/web.xml file mergewebxml produces,
          tell the war plugin to use it.
          Also, exclude what you want from the final artifact here.
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>target/web.xml</webXml>
                    <warSourceExcludes>.gwt-tmp/**</warSourceExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->

      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
          <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Any help is appreciated! If I need to provide any more info let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem was my web.xml file was located in my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml even though my war plugin was configured to get my web.xml file from there it didnt place it in my war/WEB-INF/ folder. To fix it, I manually copied the web.xml file into the war/WEB-INF dir and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the problem is exactly without seeing your pom.xml but did you configure the maven-war-plugin as described at the bottom of the [Setup Maven for GWT development](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/setup.html):

> #### Configuring maven-war-plugin
>
> Google Eclipse Plugin requires your
>   web application to be created as an
>   exploded WAR in /war (hard coded
>   path). To match this requirement, you
>   have two options :
>
> - Move your `src/main/webapp` folder to `/war` and configure
>     maven-war-plugin `warSourceDirectory`
>     parameter. This is the inplace setup,
>     as the webapp source will be used to
>     build the exploded WAR layout.
> - Configure maven-war-plugin to build the webapp in `/war`
>     (`webappDirectory` parameter) instead
>     of the standard `outputDirectory`.
>
> The gwt-maven-plugin has a boolean
>   inplace parameter to configure the
>   option you choose. The `inplace` mode
>   is interesting if you use JSPs as no
>   build/packaging/deployment is required
>   to see changes made in the JSP file.
>   Same applies to static files like CSS.

Below, a typical configuration of the maven-war-plugin for the inplace setup:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
    <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Tell me if this helps or not (in which case, don't hesitate to clarify what is unclear of what is still causing troubles).

PS: Also maybe have a look at this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894003/maven-gwt-2-0-and-eclipse).

Comment: I have already configured this. I have posted my pom.xml if that has any insights.