# Steps followed to run a GWT project with Maven dependency?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

- MAVEN-1.7
- GWT- 2.7.0
- Eclipse Luna

I have created a simple GWT project and then converted it into a Maven project. I am a new to Maven dependency and know very little about it.
Searching with Google I only find how to convert a simple project into a Maven project. Added the Maven plugin and all in Eclipse.

The Maven project consists of a `pom.xml` file. According to me we just have to add all the dependencies of the jar we are using in the project. I did this only. I had a thought that I would be able to use the classes of the jar dependency in the project, but I wasn't.

**Problem 1:**

How exactly does Maven work with GWT projects? Does it work on hosted mode
or does it also work on development mode?

**Problem 2:**

Other than dependencies do we have to add something else to the `pom.xml` file?
What are all the settings that have to be used in the `pom.xml` file?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I have studied many articles. Have converted my basic gwt project into maven project also executed it with maven dependency of gwt. But still I am stuck at places. I have some dependency like  **https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.json-lib/json-lib** not working?

I am stuck on some basic queries like this. The dependency is giving error continously. I am using couchdb in my project except fr json-lib and couchdb4j dependency other dependencies are not giving error.

I am a newbie to MAVEN, so those previous questions are not answering my query that why i raised a new question.

EDIT2:-
[image: Want these jar files]
Have got all except as told before json-lib and couchdb4j. Json-lib artifact url i have already given you but its not accepting and i tried for couchdb 4j also.

```html
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code</groupId>
   <artifactId>couchdb4j</artifactId>
   <version>0.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Whats missing then?

Answer (score 2):

@Vartika, you should've tried to check for similar questions on SO before posting a duplicate of your own! Having said that, consider going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613803/maven-and-gwt-and-eclipse-does-it-really-work) post and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894003/maven-gwt-2-0-and-eclipse) post which have detailed explanation with all the tweaks needed to get this working.

Apart from the details provided on the SO questions that I pointed out to, please go through [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/polymer-tutorial/create.html) GWT documentation as well. Hope this helps!

**EDIT 1:**

Based on the new questions that you've posted, I've done some R & D myself and a little research to get these links, a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032381/unable-to-add-couchdb4j-dependency-in-gwt-maven-project) on this issue and a [GITHUB project](https://github.com/jnorthrup/gwt-couchdb-1/blob/master/couchdb/pom.xml) that used GWT along with CouchDB. Hope this helps now!

Comment: Sir, thank you but that adding repository is not allowing me to create dataase and documents. i just mean to say its not giving me those classes which i needed nd will get through the missing couchdb-4j and json-lib